# Z, T, Chi-square, and F-tests

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Is it reasonable on a conceptual level to say that the Chi-square test is equivalent to performing a bunch of Z-tests at once, and that the F-test is equivalent to performing a bunch of t-tests at once?

[Note: I don't have very much formal statistical background]

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Stat Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-chi-squared-test-and-test-of-equal-proportion) post, a "z-test" and Chi-square can be compared to one another given they both focus on the same relationships, but you can't repeatedly run a Chi-square over and over without potentially having false-positives (or results the don't "preserve the alpha" to quote the link).

[Chi-square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) tests analyze what you observe with what you expect, and quantify that relationship.

[Z-tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-test) are how well a test statistic (under a null hypothesis) matches an approximation to the Bell curve, or normal distribution.

in Chi-square, you are looking at how well your results matched your expectations, and with z-tests you are analyzing how well your recorded data can be approximated with a normal distribution.